# Service not working after restoring solution

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have a solution with a statefull service targeting .NET 4.5.2. I add a stateless .NET Core web  service. It works and displays the home page when I run the solution.

I'm running this locally.

Then I add another service, a stateless API service which has to be .NET Core (no other options). Nothing works. I remove the API service from solution and delete the files to go back to when I just had the web service working fine.

Still nothing works. I get an error message

```
The PowerShell script failed to execute. See the Output window for details.

Output: Registration of application type failed
```

What has happened that keeps the first web service from serving the web site?

Comment: Where and how did you publish the two services? Did they target different frameworks? Your error seems to be command error, share us where you got this error.

Comment: Thank you. Ive updated with more information.